# what are ( Angular, Node.js, AJAX, JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, node.js

I really have a hard time to distinguish between all those frameworks, libraries or API I don't know, and how they related to each if they do.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: One should be simple to remove from that list as it is framework agnostic and that is AJAX. You are in the wrong line of work if you can't at least classify what those 4 items are

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some one-liner simple answers:

**Javascript** is the programming language behind all of your concepts.

**Node.js** is the runtime that runs javascript outside of a browser.

**AJAX** is the technology accessed through a browser's API where you can use javascript on a webpage to access another server (stands for "**A**synchronous **J**avascript **A**nd **X**ML", but is most often used with JSON and not XML these days).

**jQuery** is a library that makes common tasks easier in javascript in a browser (like making AJAX calls or accessing the elements on the page in a cross-platform way).

**Angular** is a framework that uses jQuery (or jqLite, a "leaner" version of jQuery) and adds much more: it provides you with patterns and pre-written code to build modern web apps using javascript, HTML, and CSS.